# "Sich handeln um" and "handeln von"

Tags: word-usage, verb, difference

What is the difference between *sich handeln um* and *sich handeln von*?

> 1. Dieses Buch handelt sich um eine schöne Prinzessin.
> 2. Dieses Buch handelt sich von einer Prinzessin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ad 1.)

*"Sich handeln um"* governs accusative as object:

> "Bei diesem Buch handelt es sich um eine schöne Prinzessin."

would be grammatically correct. Although the translation would be something like:

> This book is in fact a beautiful princess.

ad 2.)

*"Handeln von + Dat."* does not allow reflexive use. Grammatically correct would be:

> "Dieses Buch handelt von einer Prinzessin"
>    (This book is about a princess)

Simply spoken:
*"sich handeln um"* ⇒ *in fact*, clarification of a given dative object
*"handeln von + Dat."* ⇒ *be about (sth.)*

What maybe confused you is:

*"handeln von"* is synonymous to *"gehen um"*. Neither of these is reflexive though.

Comment: ITYM "Handeln von + Dat", und "sich handeln um" governs *accusative*

Comment: @Karoshi I always had difficulties discerning beween the cases... Gen, Nom, and the two others....

Answer (score 2):

Beide Sätze sind grammatisch falsch.

- `"In diesem Buch handelt es sich um eine schöne Prinzessin"` geht, oder
- `"Dies Buch handelt von einer Prinzessin"` oder
- `"Bei diesem Buch handelt es sich um eine alte Handschrift"`.

Analog für den zweiten Satz.

`Bei einem Holzscheit, der da rumliegt, handelt es sich um Buche oder Fichte` - ein Holzscheit handelt aber nie von etwas.

So wird der Unterschied hoffentlich deutlich.