# "To be about" (eg a text)

Tags: word-usage

I've seen different ways to indicate the topic of a text, film etc.
Example: "The text is about the war" (ie, talks about the war, has the war as its topic).

> 1) Der Text geht um den Krieg.
>
> 2) Im Text geht es um den Krieg.
>
> 3) Der Text handelt sich um den Krieg.
>
> 4) Der Text handelt von dem Krieg.
>
> 5) Der Text handelt über den Krieg.

Though I'm not 100% sure, I'd say I also saw

> 6) Der Text behandelt den Krieg.

Are all these different forms equivalent? Are there more?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/sich-handeln-um-and-handeln-von/8498#8498

Answer (score 5):

Here a few hints. They are not equal.

> 1) Der Text geht um den Krieg.
>
> 3) Der Text handelt sich um den Krieg.
>
> 5) Der Text handelt über den Krieg.

Wrong

---

> 2) Im Text geht es um den Krieg.

The right choice for a more informal setting.

---

> 4) Der Text handelt von dem Krieg.

In between formal and informal.

---

> 6) Der Text behandelt den Krieg.

The right choice for a formal setting.

Comment: I don't agree with them being ordered according to formality. Some just don't make any grammatical sense like this, without any supporting words.

Comment: Ok that is just my experience. In a colloquial setting nobody would use behandelt. Except Phds maybe.

Answer (score 0):

> The text is about the war.

Literal

> Der Text ist über den Krieg.

More German.

> Im Text geht es um den Krieg.

This is the best standalone sentence. All the others sound funny without context.

For example: 6) Der Text behandelt den Krieg.

This would match more to.

> The text is talking about the war.

Or

> The text is dealing with the war.

(Dealing is directly translated into handeln) Deal with is behandeln.

**Your examples in detail:**

> > 1) Der Text geht um den Krieg.

no the text goes not around the war

> 2) Im Text geht es um den Krieg.

yes but um welchen Krieg?, drop the **den**, if you are talking about war in general

> 3) Der Text handelt sich um den Krieg.

No not the text handelt sich. But:

> Die Handlung des Textes beinhaltet den Krieg.

Again welchen Krieg? Rather say Kriegshandlungen oder Krieg. Drop the "den", if there is no particular war being talked about.

> 4) Der Text handelt von dem Krieg.

Only war in this Text? Then say: Handelt ausschließlich von Krieg. But that is wrong. Again:

> Die Handlung des Textes beschreibt ausschließlich Krieg.

-

> 5) Der Text handelt über den Krieg.

The text deals over the war? Makes no sense.

Better:

> Der Text erzählt vom oder über den Krieg.

-

> 6) Der Text behandelt den Krieg.

Better

> Der Text behandelt Krieg.

Again only if you are talking about a specific war use the den.

Are there more? Yes. For example:

> Im Text dreht es sich um Krieg.
>
> Der Schwerpunkt des Textes ist Krieg.

Comment: Ich finde diese wörtlichen Übersetzungen nicht hilfreich.

Comment: Also, what's your Problem with „Der Text handelt vom Krieg“?

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of the "den". When talking about a specific war you would name it. Der Text behandelt den Zweiten Weltkrieg.

Comment: Of course, the "den Krieg" part is what I'm least interested about. That was just an example.